# How to 'visit' a site every hour with a cron job on the server?

Tags: php, wordpress, cron

I have a PHP function on my site that I want to run every hour.
The site is a Wordpress site and I have already done this in my wp-config.php: `define('DISABLE_WP_CRON', 'true');`

My function will run every time someone visits https://www.example.com/?cron
So, how can I 'pretend' that someone visit this address every hour?

I know I have to login to my server (ubuntu @ digital ocean) and write `crontab -e`
And then I will have to write `0 * * * *` and something more, this is where I need some help. 
What do I write after the last star? The address I want to visit? like `0 * * * * https://www.example.com/?cron`

Answer (score 1):

You can use curl:

```
0 * * * * curl --request GET 'https://www.example.com/?cron' >/dev/null 2>&1
```